# How to recursively print out all the nodes in a binary search tree using stringstream C++

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree, inorder

I would like to print the contents of all the nodes in my binary search tree by using a stringstream and recursion. The issue is that when I use this code, only the contents of the root are displayed. I know the reason is that every time I recursively call the function InOrder(BSTNode* bst_node), my stringstream variable is created again. What can I do to my code to fix this issue while still utilizing a stringstream for output?

This is my code:

```
string BSTree::InOrder(BSTNode* bst_node) {
  stringstream ss;
  if (root_ ==  NULL) {
    return "";
  } else {
    if (bst_node->GetLeftChild() != NULL) {
      InOrder(bst_node->GetLeftChild());
    }
    ss << bst_node->GetContents() << " ";
    if (bst_node->GetRightChild() != NULL) {
      InOrder(bst_node->GetRightChild());
    }
  }
  return ss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that maybe?

```
string BSTree::InOrder(BSTNode* bst_node)
{
  if (!bst_node)
    return "";
  ostringstream ss;
  ss << InOrder(bst_node->GetLeftChild());
  ss << bst_node->GetContents() << " ";
  ss << InOrder(bst_node->GetRightChild());
  return ss.str();
}
```

or, you can pass around the same instance of stringstream:

```
void BSTree::InOrderImpl(BSTNode* bst_node, ostringstream &ss)
{
  if (bst_node)
  {
    InOrderImpl(bst_node->GetLeftChild(), ss);
    ss << bst_node->GetContents() << " ";
    InOrderImpl(bst_node->GetRightChild(), ss);
  }
}

string BSTree::InOrder(BSTNode* bst_node)
{
  ostringstream ss;
  InOrder(bst_node, ss);
  return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: This did not work. Unfortunately, the code gives me a segmentation error.

Comment: There seems to be a typo in the first line; the if clause should be `(bst_node == NULL)`, that is no `!`.

Comment: @CarlosEscobedo perhaps it segfaults for another reason, other than that the code provided shows generic DFS traversal

Comment: the changes to the code you submitted worked. thank you

Comment: @CarlosEscobedo don't forget to accept solution. welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

Easy: just define an utility function where `stringstream` is passed as argument:

```
void BSTree::InOrder(BSTNode *root, std::stringstream &ss)
{
  if (root == nullptr) { return; }
  InOrder(root->GetLeftChild(), ss)
  ss << root->GetContents() << " ";
  InOrder(root->GetRightChild(), ss)
}

string BSTree::InOrder(BSTNode* bst_node) {
  stringstream ss;
  InOrder(bst_node, ss);
  return ss.str();
}
```

Notice that instantiating only one `stringstream` where the whole tree is dumped is probably much more efficient than instantiating a `stringstream` for each node of your tree (as it happens if you define the utility function as something taking a node and returning a string).

Answer (score 1):

My no brainer for this - pass the stringstream as argument by reference to this method:

```
static stringstream existingSSreference;
string BSTree::InOrder(BSTNode* bst_node, stringstream & ss = existingSSreference) {

  if (root_ ==  NULL) {
    return "";
  } else {
    if (bst_node->GetLeftChild() != NULL) {
      InOrder(bst_node->GetLeftChild(), ss);
    }
    ss << bst_node->GetContents();
    if (bst_node->GetRightChild() != NULL) {
      InOrder(bst_node->GetRightChild(), ss);
    }
  }
  return ss.str();
}
```

and either you want to declare the stringstream before using the method:

```
stringstream ss;
string myResult = bstreeObj->InOrder(bstNode, ss);
```

or use it without passing it

```
string myResult = bstreeObj->InOrder(bstNode);
```

this should work. Better define the stringstream outside the function and pass it when you call the function.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by Ajay, a reference argument can't have default value, unless we pass an actual existing instance as default (so that we can keep the possibility to omit the second argument).

Comment: `stringstream & ss = NULL` - will this even compile?

Comment: hm, you are right. i was thinking on testing the example, let me try and i'll update it with this correction